# PHP - UPDATE a row in a dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, html-table

I have a dynamic table that I created in HTML:

```
<table id="rounded-corner" width="51%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="19%">Job Type</th>
    <th width="24%">Job Description</th>
    <th width="19%">Type of Piping</th>
    <th width="19%">Scheduled Start Time</th>
    <th width="19%">Scheduled End Time</th>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td nowrap><?php echo $row_selectJobs['JobType']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_selectJobs['JobDesc']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_selectJobs['PipeType']; ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo substr($row_selectJobs['TimeStart'],0,-3); ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo substr($row_selectJobs['TimeEnd'],0,-3); ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_selectJobs = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectJobs)); ?>
</table>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to add a button to each row so that you can modify the contents of that row. Remember, it's a dynamic table. I'm new to PHP and I really just stole this code from Dreamweaver and modified it for my own needs.

Comment: that would be javascript and maybe ajax

Comment: ok so you have any code for me?

Comment: i would be inclined towards Jeditable http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be pretty simple to do this for. In your do loop just add another TD and use echo to output something like

```
<input type='button' class='changeRow' value='Edit' />
```

For each of the other TD's you will first want to output the values inside a span with a classname something like

```
<span class="labelValue">..What your PHP actually outputs..</span>
```

Then a hidden textbox, or something like that depending on how you want to actually do the editing. Each with a className relating to that row. so

```
<input type='text' class='editInput' value='' style='display: none;'/> etc...
```

Then using jQuery you can link it all together to make it editable like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.changeRow').click(function(){
    var tb = $(this).parents('tr').find('input.editInput');
    var label = $(this).parents('tr').find('span.labelValue');
    if($(this).val() == 'Edit'){
        tb.val(label.html());
        label.hide();
        tb.show();
                    $(this).val('Save');
    }
    else{
        label.html(tb.val());
        tb.hide();
        label.show();
                    $(this).val('Edit');
    }
});
});
```

So when your HTML is output, it would look something like this

```
  <td> <!-- The extra td for your edit button -->
      <input type="button" class="changeRow" value="Edit">Some Job Type</span>
  </td>
  <td nowrap>
      <span class="labelValue">Some Job Type</span>
      <input type="text" class="editInput" value="" style="display: none;" />
  </td>
```

Comment: Actually that jQuery wouldnt quite work because it would set all the values of a row to the same thing. You could put a loop in to find each of the controls returned by $(this).parent('tr').find('input.editInput'); and then find the span in relation to each of those values etc..

Comment: And heres a quick but not very clean example of how to do that
http://www.jameshay.co.nz/jsedit.aspx

Comment: Yup sorry, was playing around with my server. It's fixed now.

Comment: No problem. Also I would recommend JEditable as in the comments on your post. I just have a fetish for knowing exactly what's going in im my code :p

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm a rookie coder, but I was but in charge for developing applications for the company I work for. All by myself, so I don't have a lead developer to confer with.

Comment: Hey James... sorry I mean James Hay, I've been having an issue where when I click on one edit button, all the columns in every row becomes editable. Do you know what that could be.

Comment: Well compare your code to mine and try to solve the problem, it shouldn't be too difficult. A wild guess without seeing anything would be that you haven't used the parents('tr') part which will only find elements within the row that the button is on.

Comment: .closest in place of .parents